# Highcharts react X-range: how to add a custom component?

Tags: highcharts, react-highcharts

I have an x-range chart, and I need to add custom components (SVG icons) at the start of each data point ("x" prop value). Something like this (red circles are where custom components should be):

[image]

My idea is to place a custom component with position absolute, but I can't figure out how to transform timestamp values of the X axis to pixels. Or maybe there is a better solution?

[Codesandbox demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-custom-component-mobpwq?file=/src/Chart.js)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to achieve what you want:

A. You can get a chart reference and use `Axis.toPixels` method to calculate the required coordinates:

```
export default function Chart() {
  const chartComponentRef = useRef(null);
  const [x1, setX1] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartComponentRef) {
      const chart = chartComponentRef.current.chart;
      const xAxis = chart?.xAxis[0];
      const x1 = xAxis?.toPixels(Date.UTC(2022, 7, 10));
      setX1(x1);
    }
  }, [chartComponentRef]);

  return (
    <div style={{ position: "relative" }}>
      <HighchartsReact
        ref={chartComponentRef}
        highcharts={Highcharts}
        options={staticOptions}
      />
      <div style={{ position: "absolute", bottom: 70, left: x1 }}>ICON</div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-custom-componentt-ysjfh8?file=/src/Chart.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Axis#toPixels

---

B. You can also get coordinates from a point:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    if (chartComponentRef) {
      const chart = chartComponentRef.current.chart;
      const point = chart.series[0].points[2];

      setX1(chart.plotLeft + point.plotX);
    }
  }, [chartComponentRef]);
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-custom-componentt-f7nveg?file=/src/Chart.js

---

C. Use Highcharts API to render and update the custom icons:

```
  const staticOptions = {
    chart: {
      type: "xrange",
      height: 200,
      events: {
        render: function () {
          const chart = this;
          const r = 10;
          const distance = 25;

          chart.series[0].points.forEach((point, index) => {
            if (!point.customIcon) {
              point.customIcon = chart.renderer
                .circle()
                .attr({
                  fill: "transparent",
                  stroke: "red",
                  "stroke-width": 2
                })
                .add();
            }
            point.customIcon.attr({
              x: point.plotX + chart.plotLeft + r,
              y:
                point.plotY +
                chart.plotTop +
                (index % 2 ? distance : -distance),
              r
            });
          });
        }
      }
    },
    ...
  };
```

---

**Live demo:** https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-custom-componentt-f-87eof0?file=/src/Chart.js

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#circle